# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import-export' ， but I have installed import-export

Tags: django, django-import-export

I'm using Django2.2.6, xadmin2.
I want to use import-export, however, the error goes:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'import-export'
```

but I have run this code successfully

```
pip install django-import-export==2.7.0
```

Is there any way for me to fix it?

Comment: The module's name is `import_export`, not `import-export`. Was that a typo when writing this question, or is that actual error you received?

Comment: The error is can not find the module that I have installed.

Comment: I made the same error. In the documentation page https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html one is instructed to perform `pip install django-import-export` (hyphens) and then add `import_export` to `INSTALLED_APPS` (underscores).